# How to login to an email provider from objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, email, email-client

I'm working on an app that uses an email log in form within the app.

my goal is to have the application take the String from the text field (quite easy) and then post it somehow to the email provider's website's log in form, does anyone know how I might do this? and if not, does anyone have any links I might find useful?

P.S. I am writing this email client for Mac OSX, not iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is generally not how you want to do this.

Email clients access/send the users' emails using protocols such as [SMTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol), [POP3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_Office_Protocol), or [IMAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol), and not by interacting with the web interface of the email provider.

You could try using a library like [VMime](http://www.vmime.org/), which should let you connect to your users' mailboxes using the above protocols.

Comment: This answer is perfectly accurate, whoever downvoted has no clue.